# SQL WHERE question - Additional criteria for one column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm probably overthinking this but it's driving me nuts:

I'm setting up a WHERE statement to pull some specific data and there is one column that is the main criteria and another column that is a sub criteria. There are 6 values I need to pull from the main criteria column but for only one of those values I need to go down to the sub criteria level.

| CRITERIA | SUBCRITERIA |
| --- | --- |
| ITEM1 | SUBITEM |
| ITEM2 | SUBITEM |
| ITEM3 | SUBITEM |
| ITEM4 | SUBITEM |
| ITEM5 | SUBITEM |
| ITEM6 | SUBITEM2 |
| ITEM6 | SUBITEM1 |
| ITEM6 | SUBITEM2 |
| ITEM7 | SUBITEM |
| ITEM8 | SUBITEM |

I want to pull where CRITERIA IN ('ITEM1','ITEM2','ITEM3','ITEM4','ITEM5','ITEM6')

But for ITEM6 I only want where SUBCRITERIA = 'SUBITEM1'.

Whatever I try doesn't pull exactly what I want. I think I'm just blanking on something basic with the syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use an `OR` condition in the `WHERE` clause:

```sql
SELECT CRITERIA, SUBCRITERIA
FROM yourTable
WHERE CRITERIA IN ('ITEM1', 'ITEM2', 'ITEM3', 'ITEM4', 'ITEM5') OR
      (CRITERIA = 'ITEM6' AND SUBCRITERIA = 'SUBITEM1');
```

Comment: Ah, I knew it was something stupid. I just needed to add parenthesis around the whole thing. There were other clauses in the WHERE statement below this one and I was getting them grouped wrong because I didn't enclose this entire statement. DUH.  Thank you!